# English Commas to a separate non-essential part

Tags: punctuation, commas

This is a sentence from BBC.

> Some European countries, including the UK, lost their measles-free status and many developing countries, especially parts of Africa, Asia and Oceania are seeing frequent outbreaks.

I think the phrase "especially parts of Africa, Asia and Oceania" is a non-essential part of the sentence. Thus, it should be separated by a pair of commas, like below.

> Some European countries, including the UK, lost their measles-free status and many developing countries, especially parts of Africa, Asia and Oceania, are seeing frequent outbreaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed!

Be aware that BBC online journalists work under a great deal of pressure to write and illustrate their reports, often needing to attach photo, audio and video software as part of the process.

They are seldom concerned with the finer points of punctuation.

P.S. I used to be one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both lack an oxford comma.  And I would argue that the clause you refer to is not non essential. Poorly written sentence because not everything is at tweet speed.